# Find all join referenced tables in SQL

Tags: oracle

I need to extract from V$SQL all the objects (tables or views) that are referenced in all the joins of the sql.
For example: if i have this sql in the V$SQL

```
select * from ADANPT 
join BTABP on column1=column2 
left outer join HSTUDI on column3=column4
full outer join TERW on column5=column6;
```

i need to extract this:

```
BTABP
HSTUDI
TERW
```

I i have just one join in my sql, it is quite simple, using `substr` and `instr` functions (so that i extract the string from JOIN to ON words).
But i can't find a way if i have 2 or more joins. Maybe with loop?

Comment: Will your SQL statement always use ANSI join syntax (not the older Oracle syntax)? Will the join conditions always use the `on` syntax (as opposed to the `using` syntax, or the `natural join` syntax)? Can there be `cross join` (in which case there is no `on` clause)? Can there be an inline view (a subquery) in the top-level `from` clause, and if the answer is YES, how do you need to handle that? Never mind HOW to solve the problem; it's not even clear that the problem is well defined (even if you were to solve it by hand, with no assistance from a computer).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the SQL_ID and take advantage of the explain plan functionality:

```
DECLARE
  l_buff VARCHAR2(32000);
BEGIN 
  
  FOR sql_query IN (SELECT sql_ID
                      FROM v$sql
                    )
  LOOP
    l_buff := NULL;
    dbms_output.put_line('---------------'||sql_query.sql_ID||'---------------');
    FOR text_line IN (SELECT sql_text 
                        FROM v$sqltext
                       WHERE sql_id = sql_query.sql_id
                       ORDER BY piece ASC)
    LOOP
      l_buff := l_buff || text_line.sql_text;
    END LOOP;
    dbms_output.put_line(l_buff);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'explain plan for '|| l_buff;
   
    dbms_output.put_line('---------------TABLES---------------');
    FOR table_name IN (SELECT DISTINCT object_name
                         FROM plan_table
                        WHERE object_type = 'TABLE')
    LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line(table_name.object_name);
    END LOOP;
    ROLLBACK;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: You should probably be clear that this doesn't give the "objects (tables or views) that are referenced in all the joins of the sql", as asked.  This will return the tables that directly referenced views or synonyms ultimately resolve to.  That's probably better, actually, but its not what the OP asked for.